# Linking an Add-On to a Drawing

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-addons

This must be an odd question...I've searched but haven't seen anyone else ask.  It probably seems a little unnecessary, but I'm trying to assign an Add-On (not a script) to a drawing/button that would sit in cell A1 of my worksheet.

Just as you are able to assign a script to a drawing & transform it into a button, I was wondering if it is possible to somehow have a quick button to run an add-on, rather than going into the menu every time.

Just for reference - I'm looking to use the Calendar to Sheets add-on to import information directly from Google Calendar. I've looked into using a program like Automate.io, but this seems to be the best/easiest option.

Only issue is, it does not automatically update when new events are added to the calendar, meaning I will have have to run the plug-in regularly.

It seems like it is not possible, since I do not have the script...but a lot seems impossible until I come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible but if it was possible, to assign a function to a drawing you should know the name of the function and that function name should not be used on any other add-on or bounded script otherwise the results are unpredictable.

If you want to try, the first that you should do is to get the function name. The best way to get this info is from the add-on developer, so checkout the add-on documentation. If the add-on  has a dialog or sidebar created using the HTML Service you might be able to find all the public functions names by looking at the source code of the dialog/sidebar.